# Python Tkinter how to change toplevel canvas image defined in a function, in another function

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't figure out how to change an image I added in a canvas on a toplevel window in another function. I need it to change in the other function because its being constantly run by threading.
I tried using globals to global the canvas, the image and the window but I can't get it to work.

```
def openUpgrade():
  upgrade = Toplevel()
  upgrade.title("cookie clicker")
  upgrade.geometry("550x550")
  upgrade.config(bg="white")
  upgrade.bind("<Button-1>", but2)
  canvas = Canvas(upgrade, height = 550, width = 550)
  canvas.pack()
  menuBgImg1=Image.open("upgrade.png")
  resized1=menuBgImg1.resize((960,600),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  menuBgImg1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized1)
  menubg1 = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = menuBgImg1, anchor = NW)
  buy1=Image.open("buy1.png")
  resized1=buy1.resize((270,150),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  buy1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized1)
  canvasBuy1 = canvas.create_image(5, 0, image = buy1, anchor=NW)
  cookieMenuImg=Image.open("cookieIco.png")
  resized1=cookieMenuImg.resize((90,90),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  cookieMenuImg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized1)
  cookieMenu = canvas.create_image(10, 454, image = cookieMenuImg, anchor=NW)
  upgrade.mainloop()

def autoClickers():
  global cookieCount
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    cookieCount += clicker1
    print(cookieCount)
    canvas.itemconfigure(cookieText, text=str(cookieCount) + " Cookies")
    if cookieCount < 100:
      canvas.itemconfigure(canvasBuy1, image="greyBuy1.png")
    if cookieCount >= 100:
      canvas.itemconfigure(canvasBuy1, image="buy1.png")
```

I get an error telling me `canvasBuy1` is not defined

Comment: Is there another `canvas` in the root window? Otherwise you should get `canvas is not defined` exception first.  `canvasBuy1` is a local variable inside `openUpgrade()`, so it cannot be accessed elsewhere.  Either make it *global* or using class instead of function.

Comment: Also updating `tkinter` widgets in a thread is not recommended because `tkinter` is not thread safe.

Comment: Made the canvas in upgrade canvas1 so it doesent conflict with the canvas in the root and made canvasBuy1 global and canvas1 global but it says canvas1 is undefined in auto clicker

Comment: Did you run `openUpgrade()` before the auto clicker?

Answer (score 0):

I would say try to `return` the `canvasBuy1` at the end of your function.

something like:

```
def openUpgrade():
  upgrade = Toplevel()
  upgrade.title("cookie clicker")
  upgrade.geometry("550x550")
  upgrade.config(bg="white")
  upgrade.bind("<Button-1>", but2)
  canvas = Canvas(upgrade, height = 550, width = 550)
  canvas.pack()
  menuBgImg1=Image.open("upgrade.png")
  resized1=menuBgImg1.resize((960,600),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  menuBgImg1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized1)
  menubg1 = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = menuBgImg1, anchor = NW)
  buy1=Image.open("buy1.png")
  resized1=buy1.resize((270,150),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  buy1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized1)
  canvasBuy1 = canvas.create_image(5, 0, image = buy1, anchor=NW)
  cookieMenuImg=Image.open("cookieIco.png")
  resized1=cookieMenuImg.resize((90,90),Image.ANTIALIAS)
  cookieMenuImg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized1)
  cookieMenu = canvas.create_image(10, 454, image = cookieMenuImg, anchor=NW)
  upgrade.mainloop()
  return canvasBuy1
```

Using Return should let you use the CanvasBuy1 variable outside of the first function.

Comment: Added it and same name error occured saying it wasn't defined

Comment: The `return` statement will be executed only when the main root window is closed due to the line `upgrade.mainloop()`.  So when the `return` statement is executed, `canvasBuy1` has been destroyed.